# non-linear ODE $tdy + \tan^2(t+y)dt = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I really have tried to solve this equation:

That my shot:

$\tan(y+t) = u\\
\sec^2(y+t).y = du/dt\\
1+\tan^2(y+t).y = du/dt\\
(1+u^2)y = du/dt$

This is a final equation:

$t.dy/du + (1+u^2).y + u^2 = 0$

My problem is a independent variable $t$.

Comment: Let $u =y+t$ , $y'=u'-1 $ , $t(u'-1)+tan^2u=0$ and this can be solved by separable

Comment: It doesn't seem separable.

Comment: @miguel747 : Your "final equation" isn't final in fact because they are still $y$ , $t$ and $u$ in it. A correct final equation must contains only two variables, not three. It should be either an equation with $u$ and $y$, or an equation with $u$ and $t$. In fact, this will lead to nowhere because too complicated. Probably there is a typo in the initial ODE given by your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$t~dy+\tan^2(t+y)~dt=0$

$t\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-\tan^2(t+y)$

Let $u=t+y$ ,

Then $y=u-t$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{du}{dt}-1$

$\therefore t\left(\dfrac{du}{dt}-1\right)=-\tan^2u$

$t\dfrac{du}{dt}-t=-\tan^2u$

$t\dfrac{du}{dt}=t-\tan^2u$

$(t-\tan^2u)\dfrac{dt}{du}=t$

Which belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind